# Osmdroid checkout errors

Tags: android, svn, osmdroid

I have checkouted osmdroid, because I need to do some minor adjustments.

I have used: svn checkout http://osmdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ osmdroid-svn in Cmd line

Then from Eclipse -> Import -> Existing projects into Workspace

Each package has error, imports are not working, resoureces are made as a package and are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the most likely situation is you haven't got Maven set up.

you need something like m2eclipse as a maven plugin working, as all the osmdroid projects are maven projects.  without maven setup correctly, none of the dependencies etc will come down.